# Why is vlc 2.x not upgraded to the PPA 3.x version after adding the corresponding PPA for the matching Ubuntu version?

Tags: upgrade, updates, ppa, vlc

I added the VLC master PPA with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
```

and run `sudo apt-get update` and made sure that it succeeds on Ubuntu 17.04 which is supported according to [the PPA homepage](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily). The latest version from the PPA is 3.0.0~~git20170702+r70519+66~ubuntu17.04.1 which is higher than the currently installed 2.2.4-14ubuntu2. However `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` doesn't suggest the version for upgrading as it did for the dozens of PPAs I added in the last years. I repeated the preparation multiple times, so a missing `sudo apt-get update` definitely not the reason.

On the PPA homepage I see

[image]

Comment: possible it needs something that isn't available. if you have aptitude, run aptitude and look for vlc. it will list all the available versions and required packeges

Comment: I just checked, vlc is only 2.2.6

Comment: There aren't any packages in that PPA. All of vlc version 3 packages failed to build.

Comment: Then I don't understand the PPA homepage (I posted a partial screenshot after applying the filter for 17.04). Why am I seeing a 3.x package?

Comment: As mike said, no recent builds have been successful.

Comment: I understand - not that there're packages displayed although not available since this is not very "don't make me think", but that the PPA is empty. I'd accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this can be a bit confusing, you have to click on **View package details** to see the build status of the packages. There you will see that amd64, armhf and i386 architectures failed. You can drill down further and look at the build log why it failed, just start at the end of the file an work your way up.

[image]

I guess the problem is buried somewhere in here or even earlier:

```
/bin/bash: line 4: 31545 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./vlc-cache-gen `realpath ../modules`
Makefile:1634: recipe for target '../modules/plugins.dat' failed
make[4]: *** [../modules/plugins.dat] Error 139
make[4]: Leaving directory '/<<BUILDDIR>>/vlc-3.0.0~~git20170702+r70519+66~ubuntu17.04.1/bin'
Makefile:1520: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/<<BUILDDIR>>/vlc-3.0.0~~git20170702+r70519+66~ubuntu17.04.1'
Makefile:1405: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/<<BUILDDIR>>/vlc-3.0.0~~git20170702+r70519+66~ubuntu17.04.1'
dh_auto_build: make -j4 returned exit code 2
debian/rules:245: recipe for target 'override_dh_auto_build' failed
make[1]: *** [override_dh_auto_build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/<<BUILDDIR>>/vlc-3.0.0~~git20170702+r70519+66~ubuntu17.04.1'
debian/rules:232: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Build finished at 20170702-1002

Finished
--------

E: Build failure (dpkg-buildpackage died)
```

You probably have read the description:

> This package archive contains daily builds made from the VLC
>   development branch (a.k.a. the vlc.git master branch). This is meant
>   for testing purpose.
>
> Beware that the **builds are fully automated, and do not go through any
>   quality assurance** whatsoever. Functional regressions and build breaks
>   occur frequently.
>
> DO NOT USE this archive if you are not prepared to cope with such
>   problems.
>
> Please **report build breakages to the Debian/Ubuntu multimedia team**.
>   The VideoLAN developers do not have access to the build system.

I'm not sure if the Team has been informed about this and I'm not sure how to bring this to their attention after reading https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU/Teams/Media and https://wiki.debian.org/DebianMultimedia. I was able to find only [this](http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/pkg-multimedia-maintainers/2016-November/055301.html) thread about VLC 3.0 in the archives of the Debian Mailing list for the past year. It's quite puzzling an time consuming from my point of view to track this down if you haven't been involved at this level before.